# Please help me figure out what kind of a scripting language is this

Tags: javascript

I just ran across a html page which has some scripts. The script tag starts with the following line:

```
<script type="text/IMAN">
```

my question is what is a IMAN script?
I know javascript usually starts with `<script type="text/javascript">`

I changed  to , now the page shows all the code.

Comment: would you be so kind as to show us what is contained within that block?

Comment: What's inside the `<script>` tag?

Comment: Since google doesn't seem to have an answer, I would call it wtfscript.

Comment: It's probably an inside joke between some programmers of the site

Comment: Probably has something to do with: http://e.images.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/14502684.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving a browser a mime type that it doesn't understand is a great way tell it to ignore your code...allowing you to store code snippets for later - this is most commonly used in templating like https://github.com/janl/mustache.js.  Here is how it is used to store content:

```
<script type="text/template" id="template">
  <div>this is my hidden content for a popup</div>
</script>

var content = $('#template').html();
$('#popup').html(content).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify any valid MIME type (which basically just means "two identifiers separated by a slash") for the script type and the browser will ignore the content, if it doesn't recognize the type. Likely it's an HTML template or something else that the developer wants to access from Javascript but wants the browser itself to ignore. The IMAN name? Probably some injoke by the programmer.

In jQuery (for example), you could access it like:

```
$("script[type*=IMAN]").each(function() 
{
   // Do something with $(this).text() or .html() or whatever
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an invalid MIME type. The "type" attr. in an HTML `<script>` tag should contain a valid HTML mime-type. Usually its value `text/javascript` (for a Javascript resource). At any rate, there's no mime-type called text/IMAN.

Comment: It's perfectly valid, it's just unknown.

Comment: In addition MIME types are pretty extensible, so you can define whatever MIME type you like -  https://sites.google.com/a/geotoolkit.net/intviewer/other-useful-intviewer-apis/mime-types

Comment: Yes agreed, you can define any mime-type you want, but it only makes sense (and in my mind that translates to "is valid") only when you place that custom mime-type somewhere where it's actually used in some way. Placing it a script tag doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but the tag 
    `<script type='text/IMAN'>` 
is the start (open tag) for writing imanscript. Imanscript is a proprietary scripting language used by [Siemens Teamcenter PLM](https://www.plm.automation.siemens.com/global/en/products/teamcenter/). The scripting language is sort of like VBscript, but strictly for the web api programming.  The original scripting language was originally called imanscript, but in the latest version of Teamcenter it is referred to as tcscript.